# how to access xml file?

Tags: php, html, xml

Actually in my website www.musicking.in when the user selects songs one player window will open and that will access the corresponding selected songs xml playlist and the player will play those songs.

actually its working fine. but sometimes the problem is when so many users are accesiing the player not playing the songs selected, either its playing songs previously he selected or nothing.

please help me.

i stored that xml as a file in my root of website.  is there any other options to access that xml which is generated automatically when user select songs.

Comment: How is the XML file generated? Your problem looks to be a caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug might come from too much people, accessing simultenously the xml file. Try moving the content of your file into your DB. 
DB have stuff that handle multiple access and so on.

Try to explain more precisely how your website works, i'm not sure i got it.

Answer (score 0):

{My xml file will be generated from the below code}

createElement("playlist");
$dom->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttribute('version', "1");
$root->setAttribute('xmlns', "http://xspf.org/ns/0/");
$rootnext = $dom->createElement("trackList");
$root->appendChild($rootnext);
foreach ($song as $counter) {
    $tokens = ",";
    $tokenized = strtok($counter, $tokens);
// create child element

$song = $dom->createElement("track");
$rootnext->appendChild($song);
$song1 = $dom->createElement("creator");
$song->appendChild($song1);
$text = $dom->createTextNode("www.musicking.in");
$song1->appendChild($text); 
$song1 = $dom->createElement("title");
$song->appendChild($song1);
// create text node
$text = $dom->createTextNode($tokenized);
$song1->appendChild($text); 
$tokenized = strtok($tokens);
$song1 = $dom->createElement("location");
$song->appendChild($song1);
$text = $dom->createTextNode($tokenized);
$song1->appendChild($text); 

}
// save 
$dom->save("$FileName.xml");
?>